# Children's book, alien abduction, "crystals of amnesia"

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

I'm not sure about any of the following.

Children's book, possibly a collection of stories.

Aliens take a girl to their spaceship or their planet.

The aliens are agitated and show her a corridor lined with crystals where her big sister is lying motionless on the ground.

Conversation roughly along these lines:

"The crystals of amnesia.  It means 'forgetting'.  We send them through here when they leave so that they will forget what they've seen".

"What happened?"

"She stopped to examine the crystals."

*girl nods; sister is known to be crazy about science*.

"We did not realise.  She stayed too long, she has forgotten everything, how to move, how to live."

I don't remember what happened or how they rescued the sister.

Anyone know what this story was?